# Using a button to open a page containing details of a stock item

Tags: javascript, php

My intention is to show products on the index page with links. When the link is clicked a 'modal' page opend showing the details of that product.

I have a button that links to a product page, but not the other items on the index page.

How do I use this link to open each product page?

The code for button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-1">Details</button>
```

The modal:

```
    <?php
include 'details-modal-item01.php';
include 'details-modal-item02.php';
?>
```

The page details-modal-item01.php is more or less a template for the other items:

```
<div id="item01" class="modal fade item01" tableindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-1" aria-hidden="true"> -- rest of code goes here --</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of all the include jazz, which will become unmanageable once you got many products you should use ajax to load the content/partial or build from json into the modal-content section.

Ok easy said then done, so here is an example.

---

This is genrally how I do it, by using ajax and partials.

**The Link(s)**, you would need to change the `data-url=""` attribute to point to your partial.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ajax-modal" data-url="/link/to/partial" data-size="modal-md" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> Open Modal</a>
```

**The modal wrapper**. This would be placed at the bottom of your template, before `</body>`.

```
<div id="ajax-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Loading...</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Close">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body slow-warning"><p>Please wait...</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The partial**, would be served from the links endpoint, you could check the request is ajax and show the partial and if its not show a full page instead.

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Foo Bar</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"></div>
</div>
```

**Then the jquery**, which handles loading the content into the modal.

```
<script>
    var ajax_modal = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#ajax-modal').modal('show');

        var modal = '.modal-content';

        var default_content = '' +
            '<div class="modal-header">' +
            '    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>' +
            '    <h4 class="modal-title">' +
            '        Loading...' +
            '    </h4>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body">' +
            '    <p class="slow-warning">Please wait...</p>' +
            '</div>';

        $(modal).html(default_content);

        setTimeout(function() {
            if ($(document).find('.slow-warning').length > 0) {
                $(document).find('.slow-warning').html('Content failed to load, please refresh your browser and try again.');
            }
        }, 5000);

        //
        var dialog_size = $(this).data('size');

        if (dialog_size == 'modal-lg') {
            $(modal).parent().removeClass('modal-sm modal-md modal-lg').addClass('modal-lg');
        }
        else if (dialog_size == 'modal-sm') {
            $(modal).parent().removeClass('modal-sm modal-md modal-lg').addClass('modal-sm');
        }
        else {
            $(modal).parent().removeClass('modal-sm modal-md modal-lg').addClass('modal-md');
        }

        //
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false
        });

        request.done(function(data) {
            $(modal).replaceWith($('<div />').html(data).find(modal)[0]);
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log('modal failed to load', textStatus);
        });
    };

    $(document).find('.ajax-modal').off('click').on('click', ajax_modal);
</script>
```