# trying to send get value to modal

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to send the get variable from a anchor href to modal. but I cant seem to get the variable $_GET['edit2']. when I try to echo the variable it echo null which is obtain from the else statement. Thank you in advance

Part 1 : used to check if the get variable have been submitted or not.

```
if(isset($_GET['edit2'])){
        $_SESSION['reply_id'] = $_GET['edit2'];
        $reply_id = $_SESSION['reply_id'];
    }
    else{
        $reply_id = "null";
    }
```

Part 2 : the anchor href

```
<a href='?edit2=". $row2['reply_id'] ."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'><small>edit</small></a>
```

part 3 : the modal form

```
<div class='modal fade' id='myModal' role='dialog'>
   <div class='modal-dialog'>
      <!-- Modal content-->
         <div class='modal-content row'>
            <div class='col-12'>
               <div class='modal-header'>
                  <h5 class='modal-title'>Edit Reply</h5>
                  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
               </div>
               <div class='modal-body'>
                  <form id='r_edit_form' method='post'>
                     <div class='row'>
                        <label class='col-12'>Reply :</label>
                     </div>
                     <div class='row'>
                       <textarea class='col-12' form='r_edit_form' name='description' rows='4'>". $reply_id ."</textarea>
                     </div>
                     <div class='row'>
                       <input class='col-12 btn btn-dark' type='submit' name='edit_reply'>
                     </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-footer'>
                  <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475226/using-a-button-to-open-a-page-containing-details-of-a-stock-item/47475565#47475565

Comment: You can't write php code inside html without php tag...

Comment: I already write the php tag, but I don't write it here. most of my html are actually in php echo

Comment: Cool. so I assume you want to reload page on the click of link and get that value. correct??

Comment: when I click the link. a popup window will appear on the current page for me to edit the content. however when the popup appear it failed to obtain the value send by the link