# How to create multiple modals in a document using jQuery and Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The following function is able to open only one modal since it uses element `ID`.

How do I expand this function to open multiple modals?

HTML / PHP part of the code (Notice the  that is supposed to open the model)

```php
$getUsers = 'SELECT * FROM users';
  $result         = $pdo->prepare($getUsers);
  $result->execute();
  while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      if ($row['usergroup'] === "Admin") {
        echo "<tr class='table-danger'>";
      } else {
        echo "<tr>";
      }
      echo "<td><center>" . $row['username'] . "</center></td>";
      echo '<td><center><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="php/userInfo.php?id='.$row['user_id'].'" id="openUserInfoModal">View</a></center></td>';
      echo "</tr>";
}
```

Modal

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="userInfoModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Info</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div id="userModalBody" class="modal-body">

         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#openUserInfoModal').on('click',function(){
      var dataURL = $(this).attr('data-href');
      $('#userModalBody.modal-body').load(dataURL,function(){
          $('#userInfoModal').modal({show:true});
      });
  });
});
```

Once again, the first row that is displayed, you can click the *a href* and it will open the modal and display the user info. After the first row, clicking the *a href* does nothing, and does not open the modal.

Also if you delete the first row / delete the user, and the second row now becomes the first one, you can click the *a href* and it'll display the users data.

I'm really not sure what is causing this issue, but thanks for any help.

Comment: IDs are meant to be unique in HTML. In the PHP code it seems that you have a loop that generates HTML elements with the same ID.

Comment: @Titus Thanks for the response, do you have any suggestion as to how to work around this?

Comment: Also would be remiss not to note that it is a well-known UI principle that you should never have multiple modal dialogs open at the same time.

Comment: You could use a property of the user to generate unique IDs or even easier, use the iteration's index to do that or use class names and find the appropriate modal based on which button was pressed.

Comment: @JaredSmith - I am not trying to open multiple modal dialogs at the same time.

Comment: @Russell this will help if you want to use ajax to load int the contents, then you only have 1 modal wrapper.. no use in filling out the dom if its never looked at.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475226/using-a-button-to-open-a-page-containing-details-of-a-stock-item/47475565#47475565

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this, is that you are duplicating the `id` of the `a` element. So, when you click on any of them, `jQuery` is actually using only the first one. So, you would need to change it, so as instead of using an id, you would use a class to open the modal.

**PHP**

```
$getUsers = 'SELECT * FROM users';
  $result         = $pdo->prepare($getUsers);
  $result->execute();
  while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      if ($row['usergroup'] === "Admin") {
        echo "<tr class='table-danger'>";
      } else {
        echo "<tr>";
      }
      echo "<td><center>" . $row['username'] . "</center></td>";
      echo '<td><center><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="php/userInfo.php?id='.$row['user_id'].'" class="openUserInfoModal">View</a></center></td>';
      echo "</tr>";
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.openUserInfoModal').on('click',function(){
      var dataURL = $(this).attr('data-href');
      $('#userModalBody.modal-body').load(dataURL,function(){
          $('#userInfoModal').modal({show:true});
      });
  });
});
```